# which file can install a program on windows 7?

Tags: windows, installation

Which of these files( in setup folder), if execute can install a program on windows 7 ?

`1- setup.com
 2-setup.ini
 3-setup.inf`

Comment: Nothing like `setup.exe`?

Comment: which file is like as setup.exe?

Comment: I would say none of those in your list. It looks suspicious...

Comment: it's one of my exam questions... :(

Comment: Fire the examiner. Though `.com` files are executable (see answer below), it is not a standard to start installation using this type of file.

Comment: Technically only the .com file is an executable (like an .EXE without the header information, technically the old DOS version of an executable). .INF would be passed as a parameter to RUNDLL32 with the expectation that it contains driver installation details, and .INI is normally passed to Notepad for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM files are executable in Windows. You should be able to run `setup.com` from the CMD prompt by `cd`ing to the directory `setup.com` is in, and running `setup` or `setup.com`.

Keep in mind, COM files cannot be executed on 64-bit versions of Windows, since these editions lack **NTVDM**, the MS-DOS-emulating subsystem that handles COM file execution. You would instead need to emulate the 32-bit environment using an emulator like DOSBox.

Comment: While what you say is true about actual COM files, also be aware that most of the executable files that you come across nowadays with the COM file extension are not actually COM files. For example, Visual Studio ships with the devenv.com file that is actually just an EXE file with a different extension.

Answer (score 0):

setup.inf can be used to file copy and installation. I cannot remember setup.com installers for Windows programs.

[msdn inf description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/install/overview-of-inf-files)